# Could a combined magnetic field provide structural integrity?

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields, rotational-dynamics, material-science, elasticity

Imagine 2 rings made of a magnetic material the outer magnetically suspended ring spins at its maximum rotational velocity. The inside of the first magnet ring is south on the inside and the inner ring is south on the outside.

Will the magnetic fields of the first ring counteract on the rotational stress of the inner ring creating magnetic structural integrity onto and allowing the inner ring to physically spin beyond its mechanical failure point?

Now, add more inner rings on spinning a little faster than the other. Can the combined magnetic ring spin incrementally faster because they are held together magnetically from mechanically failing or spinning apart?

***The rings are not to scale. The rings may need to be magnetically bracketed with a base magnet if the poles cannot be shaped to remain self-entrapped.***

[image]

Comment: @PM2Ring corrected.tks

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with quantum mechanics. But it does relate to relativity.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing special happens as the outer ring rotates. If we use rings with real small thicknesses, the revolving of any of them around its center produces no tangible electric field circularly surrounding the ring. Even if there is any such electric field, it cannot set the inner ring magnet into motion.

And, even if you slightly rotate the inner ring, while the outer one rotates very fast, the net force on each infinitesimally small element of the inner ring is almost zero with a direction along the ring's radius, and not perpendicular to it to make it rotate faster or slower.