# Are flywheels capable of converting torque to foward momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, magnetic-moment

I drew a picture of two flywheels counter-rotating in synch. While they are undergoing angular acceleration, would they propel forward? Can they be moved to reverse the torque to again propel forward?
[image]

one would just spin in place, but 2 accelerating against each ether in the right position should move forward?

[Swimming in Spacetime - apparent conserved quantity violation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/886/97)

[Could a combined magnetic field provide structural integrity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528795/could-a-combined-magnetic-field-provide-structural-integrity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them on either side of a belt that is held tightly in place.

Then they will move sideways against the belt.

Without the belt, they won't move sideways.

Answer (score 1):

> While they are accelerating, would they propel forward?

Not without an external force. The conservation of momentum requires an external force for the center of mass of a system to accelerate.

Angular and linear momentum are separately conserved and cannot be converted into each other. However, as drawn this system would not get any net angular momentum either since the angular momentum of one disk will be equal and opposite the other.

Comment: Back in the 1950's a lot of people got excited about the "Dean Drive" https://patents.google.com/patent/US2886976A/en, which was supposed to work by a vaguely similar principle to what you propose.  Unfortunately, it can't work - and didn't work.